# Adding extra object property to knockout mapping

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I have a data from server that as follow.

```js
var data = [{
  'Name': 'David',
  'Class': '2A'
}, {
  'Name': 'Vincent',
  'Class': '2B'  
}]
```

Suppose that i retrieve the data and map it using ko.mapping.fromJS. However, I would like to make the data to consist of another property name Grade after mapping. How can this be achieved? This is because the value of property grade is retrieved through another ajax call, and it should be defined beforehand.

```js
function MyViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.StudentProfile = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  self.GetStudentProfile = function() {
    $.ajax({
       ..
       ..
       success: function(data) {
          ko.mapping.fromJS(data.StudentProfile, {}, self.StudentProfile);
          // data after mapping 
          $.each(self.StudentProfile, function (index, value) {
            $.ajax({
                ..
                ..
                success: function(data) {
                   self.StudentProfile()[index].Grade(data);
                }
            });
          }
       }
    })
  }
}

// data after mapping
var data = [{
  'Name': 'David',
  'Class': '2A',
  'Grade': ''
}, {
  'Name': 'Vincent',
  'Class': '2B',
  'Grade': ''
}]
```

Comment: Have you tried self.StudentProfile()[index].Grade=ko.observable(data); instead of self.StudentProfile()[index].Grade(data); ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
var options = {
    create: function(options){
        options.data.Grade = ko.observable("");
        return options.data;
    }
}
```

`ko.mapping.fromJS(data.StudentProfile, options, self.StudentProfile);`